# Sort a list using both alphabatically and Integer in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, list, timestamp

I have a text file which contains `timestamp` and `exception name`.

Text file looks something like this.

```
1573594032526 NullPointerException
1573594032527 NullPointerException
1573594032528 IllegalAgrumentsException
1573596032526 UserNotFoundException
1573597032526 NullPointerException
```

I have converted them into `hour`, `minute` and `second` by:

```
                data = []
                for line in resp.text.splitlines():
                    split_ = line.split()

                    date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(split_[1]) / 1000)

                    data.append({
                        "second": date.second,
                        "minute": date.minute,
                        "hour": date.hour,
                        "data": split_[-1],   ------> exception name
                    })
```

I have to sort them according to `timestamp` as well as `name` i.e the output should be:

```
21:15-21:30 IllegalAgrumentsException 1,
21:15-21:30 NullPointerException 2,
22:00-22:15 UserNotFoundException 1,
22:15-22:30 NullPointerException 1,
```

so in this case timestamp for `NullPointerException` and `IllegalAgrumentsException` are same(in terms of hours,minutes and second) so alphatically `IllegalAgrumentsException` comes first.
Also at end of each line the `number` is count of exceptions in that time range.

How can I acheive this ?

Comment: Can you use `pandas` library?

Comment: yes, we can use pandas @ShubhamSharma

Comment: Whats the logic behind obtaining the values like `21:15-21:30` from timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

Read the data into pandas dataframe, convert timestamp in the required form and then sort as below:

```
df.sort_values(by=['timestamp', 'exception_name'])
```

And the last column can be achieved using

```
df.groupby(['timestamp','exception_name']).transform('count')
```

Comment: I can't sort it using timestamp since when you convert timestamp into hour,minute,second then they are same for first 3 line of file otherwise timestamp are different. correct me if i am wrong ?@sam

Comment: Is it possible for you to first sort using normal timestamp and then convert timestamp to hour, minute, sec at the end.

Comment: actually if we sort it using normal timestamp then we can't get the expected output for example - `1573594032528` -> `21:27:12` and `1573594032526` -> `21:27:12` are same so output will be `NullPointerException` first and than `IllegalAgrumentsException` but I want the opposite.@sam

Comment: This is the answer I get when I sort with the first line in my answer:
           timestamp                exception_name
0 1573594032526 NullPointerException
1 1573594032527 NullPointerException
2 1573594032528 IllegalAgrumentsException
3 1573596032526 UserNotFoundException
4 1573597032526 NullPointerException

Comment: First exception should be `IllegalAgrumentsException ` right.?